# why is the print() function prints none in this case

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, printing, nonetype

I've been working on a problem I don't understand why the recursive function step returns None?

here is the code :

```
import sys

def minIndx(list):
    x=10
    indx=0
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if (list[i]<x):
            x=list[i]
            indx=i
    return indx

def steps(arr,sum1,sum2,x):
    i = minIndx(arr)
    del arr[i]
    sum1 = sum(arr)
    if (sum1 + 9*x >= sum2):
        return x
    else: steps(arr,sum1,sum2,x+1)

s=input()
digits1=[]
digits2=[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    if (i>2):break
    digits1.append(int(s[i]))
for i in range(len(s)):
    if (i<3):continue
    digits2.append(int(s[i]))
sumLeft = sum(digits1)
sumRight = sum(digits2)
print(steps(digits1,sumLeft,sumRight,1))
```

for the test case : 123456,
the step function prints None as well as the print function

Comment: In the else in `steps`, you aren't returning anything. Every branch of execution must return something when you're using recursion. Just return the result of the recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you're not returning your recursive call. What is your expected output here? When I return the recursive call to steps I get a value of 2 for an input of 123456.